# Testing File/Folder Navigation and Manipulation

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am working on a module that supplies methods for navigating directories and manipulating files. Basically it will be a combination of the `Dir` and `File` classes, with options specific to the needs of a project I'm working on.

Right now I have started writing tests for some of these methods and things are getting messy.

#### Example

One of the methods I have is a `tree` function that returns a hash of files and folders where you can pass options like `tree(only: 'folders', limit: 3)`. In order to test that it only goes down 3 levels, I would have to have 4+ subfolders with dummy files in them.

#### The Problem

Right now I'm testing on folders outside the project since the subfolders are already there, but I want to move away from this, especially considering the implausibility of testing on system files once I start testing methods equivalent to `rm -rf` (as well as the lack of portability).

I'm starting to think that I need to create a "lab rat" type folder that I do all my "experiments" on, but I have no clue how to approach creating it.

- Do I create a function that creates the files?
- Do I pull files and folders from another location?
- Do I use some sort of "lorem ipsum" generator for file structures?
- Do I make all these files and folders manually(ugh)?
- Do I just mock and stub the hell out of everything and not actually create/delete the files and folders?(I don't see this happening)

So...

How would someone normally approach testing excessive amounts of file and folder manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use mocks/stubs. The file system of your OS should be well tested and fast, so the benefit of mocks/stubs is minimal. Creating a mock/stub system increases the complexity without much benefit.

Here's my answers:

**Do I create a function that creates the files?** 
 
Yes. You can create tests for these functions to make sure that they are correct. Instead of calling `Dir` and `File`, write helper functions that make the code simple and readable. Maybe you can share the helper functions between the source/test code...

**Do I pull files and folders from another location?** 
 
Not sure what this is for...

**Do I use some sort of "lorem ipsum" generator for file structures?**

Yes, if you mean create functions that generate file structures.

**Do I make all these files and folders manually(ugh)?**
No.

**Do I just mock and stub the hell out of everything and not actually create/delete the files and folders?(I don't see this happening)**
No. One benefit of creating files/directories is that you can manually check what is going on and not be 100% dependent on the tests. This is actually a good approach because without it there could be a bug where both the source code and test code is not doing what you expect, but you wouldn't know because everything ***seems*** to be working.